# How to find the path from where an app is started?

Tags: vb.net

I put my EXE files (usually to edit/convert ASCII files) in an own directory. The directory path is also put in the PATH variable of the system, so I can start the programs from anywhere. So here my question:
Is there a way (in VB.net) to find from where I started my program?
I need to know that to put that path as initial directory for the openFile-Dialogues.
Thanks for your help,
Jan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a quite simple answer. I already tried it once, but apparently under different circumstances. The right function is just CurDir(). Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to do this. Here are two:

```
System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory()
```

Or:

```
Application.StartupPath
```

Both will return strings of the path where your app was started.

Read more:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.basedirectory(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath(v=vs.110).aspx

---

**EDIT:**

There is also this way, which checks the path based on the current executing/executed assembly:

```
System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase)
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa457089.aspx

But personally I'd recommend the above two.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this gets me the directory, where the EXE file is, but not the path from where I started it. Maybe I can be more precise: I use the FreeCommander Software, where I can start Programs via commandline. There, when I'm in the directory of the files I want to manipulate with my Program, I just type in the name of the EXE file. This EXE is somewhere else, and is find because the directory path of the EXE file is saved in the PATH Variable. But I need to get the path of the folder, where I have the files to manipulate.

Comment: @Jan-Henrik : Well you were not very precise about that in your initial question. It sounded to me that you wanted the folder of the current instance of your app. So you want to open your application from the `FreeCommander Software` app, and then have your application get the folder of the app who opened it?

Comment: No, not the folder of the app, but the folder from where I start the app. Like, when you're in DOS mode. The app's path is "C:\myPrograms\myApp.EXE". I am in the folder "C:\myFiles\" and type "myApp.EXE" to start it. And I want to set the initial Directory for the openFileDialog in the app to "C:\myFiles\"

Comment: You didn't start the app _from_ that folder. But you were in it when you executed the application. The application is always started from the folder where it is located. So there's a difference. :)

Comment: @Jan-Henrik : As for me clearly understanding what you mean now, I can asnwer with that I don't think it's possible for your app to determine which folder the instance of the `FreeCommander Software` app is in. So if you want your app to have a variable storing that path, I suggest you pass it via the commandline args: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1